# Calculate $(i+1)^x$ to a certain power of x

Tags: complex-numbers

I was just wondering what is the best way to calculate (i+1) to a certain power? Say if x was = 37, what are sort of the general steps? Obviously, I could just brute force and then find some sort of pattern, but I was wondering if there is already a sort of algorithm/formula existing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it in the polar form.
$$1+i = \sqrt{2} e^{i \pi/4}$$
That makes it easier to calculate the exponent:
$$(1+i)^{37} = \sqrt{2}^{37} e^{i 37 \pi/4}$$
With some simplification:
$$(1+i)^{37} = {2}^{18}\sqrt{2} e^{i 5 \pi/4}$$
Observe that:
$$\sqrt{2} e^{i 5 \pi/4} = -1-i$$
So:
$$(1+i)^{37} = -2^{18}-2^{18}i$$
Then a calculator will tell you $2^{18}=262144$ and you are finished.

Comment: Oh that makes way more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could use Binomial expansion
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)x^ky^{n-k}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the base in trigonmetric form. $1+i$ becomes $\sqrt{2}(cos(\pi/4)+i sin(\pi/4))$. Then use De Moivre's theorem to raise it to a power, in this case to the 37th. The theorem says that if a complex number $z$ is written in trigonometric form as $z=r(cos(x)+i sin(x))$, then $z^n=r^n(cos(nx)+i sin(nx))$.

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiating complex numbers is usually made efficiently using their *polar representation*. Write $z=1+\mathrm i$ as $z=\rho\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}$. Then $z^x=\rho^x \mathrm e^{\mathrm i x\theta}$.